# About finitely generated lattices in Lie groups

Tags: lie-groups, lattices

Let $G$ be a connected Lie group. Let $\Gamma$ a lattice in $G$ not necessarily uniform (cocompact). Is it true that $\Gamma$ is finitely generated?

Comment: I think one old ingredient is that the lattice meets the connected amenable radical in a cocompact lattice. This being said, this reduces to the semisimple case (without compact factor). In this case, it meets the center in a finite index subgroup, which reduces to lattices in semisimple groups with no compact factor and trivial center. Then one reduces to irreducible lattices. Kazhdan's property T allows to conclude when at least one factor has Property T. In the remaining case we have a product of rank 1 groups. Maybe the case of 1 vs several factors is done separately.

Comment: @YCor That's why I find Gelander & Slutsky's uniform proof interesting.

Comment: @DaveBenson But this paper quickly relies on essential steps of my above sketch. Namely Auslander's theorem that the lattice meets the (nonconnected) amenable radical in a lattice. This directly reduces to the case of semisimple groups with trivial center. One this is said, possibly there's a unified proof; now everything should be in Gelander's previous 2011 paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1102.3574. (But I would have guess that for semisimple groups Borel-Serre already provides a uniform proof.) Anyway I insist that these are separate (important) steps in the claimed "unified" proof.

Comment: By the way these approaches (inspired by Borel-Serre: retracting the symmetric space by deformation) usually prove better than finite generation, namely that such lattices have a finite $K(G,1)$ — and actually one that is a compact manifold (with boundary).

Comment: Thank you @YCor! I tried to search about `` Borel-Serre: retracting the symmetric space by deformation" but I did not find a related reference.

Comment: I had in mind (among others?) A. Borel and J.-P. Serre, Corners and arithmetic groups, Comment. Math. Helv., 48 (1973),
pp. 436–491. With an appendix: Arrondissement des variétés à coins, par A. Douady et L. Hérault. The latter addresses arithmetic groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

J. Lie Theory 30 (2020), no. 1, 33–40, arXiv:1903.04828 Gelander and Slutsky, "On the minimal size of a generating set for lattices in Lie groups", Corollary 1.6 says yes, and says it is "well known but non-trivial".

Comment: Thank you @Dave_Benson! I am wondering where the theorem was proven the first time?

Comment: Originally a combination of bits and pieces.